# How to combine Xlookup, to match another column, but if it returns an N/A, match it with the first 2 characters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(C2,'_MSA''s to Fac'!F:F,'_MSA''s to Fac'!K:K)
```

that pulls matched data from another column; however, some values are returning as N/A. How can i combine my xlookup to tell me for the values retuning as N/A, to instead match with the first 2 characters of the return array?

Comment: Not sure what you are after without sample data but there is a parameter available just for that. Another option is to wrap in `IFERROR()`.

Comment: @JvdV essentially my lookup is working, but some values are showing up as N/A. I want my formula to also say, for the values that are showing up as N/A match the lookup value with the first 2 characters of the return array

Comment: JvdV's suggestion of `iferror` should work.

Comment: @findwindow not "ISNA" ?

Comment: `iferror` covers more than just NA but sure.

Comment: =iferror(first_lookup,second_lookup) if the first lookup fails then iferror will move to the second. Do test it.